# Deposition of elemental sulfur

Tags: organosulfur-compounds

I want to create a thin film of elemental sulfur. Based on significant searching, I can find that elemental sulfur deposition is a significant problem in oil and gas. However, I cannot find any specifications for depositing elemental sulfur via CVD, ALD, or other methods.

Can anyone suggest a method for creating a thin film of elemental sulfur? Thanks!

Comment: Evaporation would seem to be a direct way. The melting point is so low that it should be pretty easy in either a boat or e-gun system. Watch for sulfur-metal interactions on the boat. It may also react upon opening the system up.

Comment: Can you explain a little more exactly what you mean? I have previously tried sublimation, as mentioned in the paper "A binder-free sulfur/carbon composite electrode prepared by a sulfur sublimation method for Li–S
batteries" by Cui et al. However, I found that very little sulfur actually deposited and it was not possible to obtain a full film. However, my processing may have been imperfect.

Comment: Reaction of copper sulfate and sodium thiosulfate in a 1 to 1 ratio.